# Is there a shortcut to toggle "display: none/block" in element's style in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, shortcut, chrome-dev-editor

In Chrome DevTools there is a shortcut to show/hide an element:

[image]

Chrome adds `__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__` class to the element, but it is nothing more than `visibility: hidden`:

[image]

Is there similar shortcut to change element's `display: none/block` style? So on click it adds `style='display: none;'` attribute and toggles it `none/block`?

[image]

Comment: Why `none/block` instead of `none/inline`, `none/table-row-group`, ... ?

Comment: @Oriol, good option, why not? Do you know how?

Comment: No idea. I was just pointing the difficulty of implementing a feature like this, because if you toggle between `none` and `block` some people would want `inline` instead of `block`. The root of the problem is that `display` was awfully designed, hopefully `box-suppress` introduced by Display L3 will fix this.

Comment: If you edit the rules of the `__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__` class in Chrome's devtools, they will remain modified until you refresh. So you _could_ replace `visibility: hidden` with `display: none` and use `h` as your toggle key. This may be an acceptable compromise if you don't do this too often.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such shortcut. What you can do instead is use <kbd>backspace</kbd> to remove the element from the DOM and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to bring it back.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install this chrome extension:

[亲爱的.**web-inspector-hide-shortcut**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E4%BA%B2%E7%88%B1%E7%9A%84web-inspector-hide-sho/dhnnbinlljmoaelohfghoeggalkdncbi)

It overrides the default css from `"visibility: hidden"` to `"display: none"`

Though, I'm not the author, the idea/implementation is simple, see [source](http://bricss.net/post/64013104469/quickly-toggling-elements-in-the-web-inspector)

Pretty much just add one additional css layer

from

```
.__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__, .__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__ * {
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

to

```
.__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__ {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We can hide the element by pressing some number of keys. You can do this in this way.

- firstly, click on the div in the Devtools that you want to hide.
- then type the keys in this 'width' on your keyboard.
- now that particular element will get hidden and you will see this to be written in you 
  div style '**web-inspector-hide-shortcut**'

By doing this your element will hide, you don't need to apply 'display: none' to it.

Remember, this shortcut is reversible and to apply 'display: block' attribute, just do the same on the particular component.